# How to read all files containing in a sub folder for external tables in Sql Server Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server-2016, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I have to load the data from datalake to sql server data warehouse using the polybase tables.I have created the set up for the creation of external tables.i have created the external table with location as "/A/B/PARQUET/*.parquet/". But i'm getting invalid path error.Under PARQUET folder there are subfolders with name.parquet,under that folder it has .parquet files.As there is no path called *.parquet.but how to get all the sub-folders(.parquet) under PARQUET folder?
Is there any way to get all sub folders containing .parquet files under PARQUET folder.Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[EXT_TEST1]
( A VARCHAR(10),B VARCHAR(20)) 
(DATA_SOURCE = [Azure_Datalake],LOCATION = N'/A/B/PARQUET/*.parquet/',FILE_FORMAT =csvfileformat,REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,REJECT_VALUE = 1)

folder structure:
A->B->PARQUET->asdfolder.parquet-> file1.parquet
             ->dfgfolder.parquet-> file2.parquet
             ->shdfolder.parquet-> file3.parquet
```

Comment: Under A/B/PARQUET are there any files which aren’t Parquet files? If not, just remove “*.parquet” from your path and it will search sub folders. I don’t believe you can do wildcards.

Comment: @GregGalooway-Thanks for your reply.there are only parquet files under sub folders.It worked for me  able to get all files data in ext table.Is there any alternate way other than this?
and while doing select * from ext table i'm getting the below error.
HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class parquet.io.api.Binary (java.lang.Double is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; parquet.io.api.Binary is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
can u please let me know the issue

Comment: i have used /A/B/PARQUET/ it worked fine for me

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted this as the answer. If you wouldn't mind clicking the green checkmark that will help others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the location to:

```
LOCATION = '/A/B/PARQUET'
```

Polybase will load all files in that folder and subfolders. The only exception is files or folders which begin with a period (`.`) or an underscore (`_`) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017?#arguments).